# Q: Boolean Structure

Tags: openfda

I'm looking for help to construct a search with multiple parameters. Is this possible? I'm basically performing this search to try to catch reports that may have been labeled with the incorrect product code. I believe this report should show results for a couple reports with DQY product code and 246 results, but right now it is only giving 243 results.

https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20130401+TO+20180430]+AND+device.manufacturer_d_name:(Jude+Medtronic)+AND+device.device_report_product_code:DRC+device.brand_name:(Needle+AND+(Transceptal+Brocken+BRK)))

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Edit 10/20/2018.
After testing my claim, I've realized the brand_name field is exact, and requires the search terms to be in parentheses. The following is my successful search:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20130401+TO+20180430]+AND+device.manufacturer_d_name:(Jude+Medtronic)+AND+(device.device_report_product_code:DRC+device.brand_name:(%22needle%22+AND+(%22transseptal%22+%22brockenbrough%22+%22brk%22)))&limit=100&skip=0

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get the impression that 3 results are missing? Your search query looks good to me. When you know that 3 results are missing you should be able to identify them and isolate them from the other 243 results. Then you can further investigate these 3 results and especially their fields you were searching for and the corresponding values.

There is just one thing i would add to your query, extra parenthesis around `( device.device_report_product_code:DRC+device.brand_name:(Needle+AND+(Transceptal+Brocken+BRK)) )`for clarification purposes.

Edit 20 Oct 2018 by the OP:

After testing my claim, I've realized the brand_name field is exact, and requires the search terms to be in parentheses. The following is my successful search:

```
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20130401+TO+20180430]+AND+device.manufacturer_d_name:(Jude+Medtronic)+AND+(device.device_report_product_code:DRC+device.brand_name:(%22needle%22+AND+(%22transseptal%22+%22brockenbrough%22+%22brk%22)))&limit=100&skip=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the AnswerComment! This made me realize I can test my logic further. For a little more background, I know that my desired search should have 246 because in my previous project, I downloaded all the adverse device event files from the fda website directly, and imported them to a sql database, which I did my search on. Back to our problem at hand. I tested out my claim, and found that the brand_name field is an exact field, so needs quotation marks. My new search is performing as expected. See edit above.